# Fetch list of all facebook page of a user from my Android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I am developing an Android app and one of its feature is to fetch all Facebook's page. I know how to fetch information of a logged in user, but I also want to get list of pages created by that user. I searched everywhere on [developer.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page) and also tried [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=platform) but couldn't find list of pages created by that logged in user.

I know ways to get all information of a particular page but that is not what I want. Please help me in this issue with some links or snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the

```
/me/accounts
```

endpoint to receive the list of Pages the logged-in User created. Be sure to grant the "manage_pages" permission!

Comment: It worked..but how to also post images/videos as the Admin of page ?

Comment: RTM: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed/#publish Please accept my answer, because I answered your original question.

Comment: The method u just specified is for the non-admins..can u suggest a method for the user having admin rights ?

Comment: You're welcome. For posting to a page please be sure to use the appropriate page access token you got with the /me/accounts call

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "admin rights". Do you mean posting as the  page itself? If so, the docs state "A page access token with publish_actions permission can be used to publish new posts on behalf of that page."

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47776/discussion-between-nilayonandroid-and-tobi)

Comment: I'm working on same thing , i also want to get the pages, please can you share the code you used to get list of pages which i admin?please guide me